# Enable security settings in Internet Explorer 7 via registry

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-registry, ssl, internet-explorer-7

I used to have a list of keys to enable various security settings within Internet Explorer 7 via the Registry. Specifically, I'm looking for the keys that enable SSL 2 and 3.

Comment: Keep in mind, that SSL, especially v2, is considered insecure nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at Microsofts' [Tweakomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bd328d1e-6c01-4447-bd7c-c09646d722c8&displaylang=en), it allows you to set IE security settings.

I had a similar issue to this that I posted on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/76351/how-to-automatically-set-ie-settings-for-all-users)